# Built-in way to simulate a while loop without side effects

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Generally the boilerplate of while loop looks like(`r` is the result I want, `p` is the predictor:

```
var r, p;
while(p()) {
  (r, p) = compute(r)
}
```

I can convert it into a recursion to get rid of `var`:

```
def f(r) = {
  val (nr, p) = compute(r)
  if(p()) nr
  else f(nr)
}
```

Is there a built-in way to implement such logic? I knew `Iterator.continually`, but it seems still to take a `var` to store side effect.

Comment: You have no initial value of `p`. Do you mean `do {...} while(p())`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def compute(i: Int): (Int, () => Boolean) =
  (i - 1) -> { () => i > 1 }
```

To create an immutable `while` you'll need `iteration` - a function that accepts `state` and returns new `state` of same type plus exit condition.

#### Iterator.continually

It's not the best solution - in my opinion this code is hard to read, but since you mentioned it:

```
val (r, p) = Iterator.continually(()).
  scanLeft( 13 -> { () => true } ){
    case ((r, p), _) => compute(r)
  }.dropWhile{ case (r, p) => p() }.
  next
// r: Int = 0
// p: () => Boolean = <function0>
```

You could use `val (r, _) =` since you don't need `p`.

If you want a solution with `Iterator` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20726478/406435) with `Iterator.iterate`.

#### Tail recursion

I  guess this is an idiomatic solution. You could always rewrite your `while` loop as tail recursion with explicit state type:

```
@annotation.tailrec
def lastWhile[T](current: T)(f: T => (T, () => Boolean)): T = {
  val (r, p) = f(current)
  if (p()) lastWhile(r)(f)
  else r
}

lastWhile(13){ compute }
// Int = 0
```

#### Scalaz unfold

In case you are using [`scalaz`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) there is such method already. It produces a `Stream`, so you should get the last element.

At the end of an iteration you should produce an `Option` (`None` is an exit condition) with `Pair` of stream element (`r`) and next state `(r, p())`:

```
unfold(13 -> true) { case (r0, p0) =>
  val (r, p) = compute(r0)
  p0.option(r -> (r, p()))
}.last
// Int = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this really answers the question of "built-in." I don't believe there's a solution that is simpler to implement or understand than your recursive routine. But here's another way of attacking the problem.

You can use `Iterator.iterate` to create an infinite iterator, and then find the first element that fails the predicate.

```
// Count until we are greater than 5
def compute(r: Int): (Int, () => Boolean) = {
  (r + 1, () => (r < 5))
} 

// Start at the beginning
val r = 1
val p = () => true


// Create an infinite iterator of computations
val it = Iterator.iterate((r, p))({
  case (r, _) => compute(r)
})

// Find (optionally) the first element that fails p. Then get() the result.
val result = it.find({ case (_, p) => !p() })
  .map { _._1 }
  .get
```

Comment: You don't need `toSeq`  here. And you could replace `var` with `val` to stress that you don't need `var`s (`but it seems still to take a var to store side effect.`).

Comment: The 'var's were a typo. I'd just forgotten to switch them to val. As you say, this works fine with vals. Thanks for the note about toSeq; some part of an intermediate design required a Seq and I forgot to remove it.